# How to read DeltaTable on azure storage account using GraphQL?

Tags: python, graphql, azure-functions, delta-lake

I'm looking for different ways to read `DeltaTable` on Azure Storage account using API's.
One option i find is using `delta-rs` to read the Delta Table and expose that as `Azure Functions`.

I was wondering is there anyway, we could use `GraphQL` to read the Delta tables and expose that as Azure Functions.

Comment: I guess there isn't native support for Delta tables in Azure Storage within GraphQL. maybe you need a custom solution.

Comment: @MohamedAzarudeenZ what do you mean custom solution? could you share something?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes. GraphQL is *middleware*. You could use GraphQL to create a type structure that represents your data then write *resolvers* that read the delta table. Your GraphQL server can then be exposed as an Azure function.

Note that GraphQL has no particular knowledge of *any* storage system. It can be used over SQL, noSQL, graph databases (ex: Neo4J), REST APIs, cloud databases, file systems, etc…

- [Deploying an Apollo GraphQL server as an Azure function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/deployment/azure-functions/) (js)
- [Serverless GraphQL on Azure using Python](https://www.vizeit.com/serverless-graphql-api-on-azure-using-python/) (python)